# Why does adding a high-pass or low-pass EQ increase volume?

Tags: frequency-spectrum, amplitude, equalizer

The following three screenshots show the max volume levels (indicated above the VU meter) of Cuckoo by Tipper if played with:

1. No EQ: -0.5db Headroom

[image]

2. High Pass EQ: +2.5dB over

[image]

3. Low Pass EQ: +0.4dB over

[image]

---

I don't understand why this would happen.  I saw a theory somewhere that cutting high's basically turns square waves into sines (and the amplitude of their fundamental is higher that way).  Is that true?

And what's the reasoning behind the High Pass adding so much?

Comment: This really depends on your input signal. What are you feeding it ? Has the input been "peak limited" already ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possibilities:

1. The highpass filter has a gain > 1 in parts of its magnitude response. Together with the spectrum of your input signal, this leads to a fullband signal level increase, that more than compensate for the loss of energy due to the loss of low frequencies.
2. The equalizer is non-linear phase. By re-aligning parts of the spectrum, this happens to cause an increase in peak signal level. Some radio processing does the opposite: mess around with phase distortion until peaks happen to be redused, thus allowing for a slight increase in non clipped output level.

Comment: For #2, what is this process called?  Can I buy a tool that does it?

Comment: «Phase rotator», I believe. https://gearspace.com/board/mastering-forum/814899-phase-rotator.html